# Ajax code is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have this program in which the user enters a city and a country. The program looks in the database to see if the city doesn't already exists, if it does I show a warning message using ajax, if not i add the city to the database.

This is the form:

```
<form action="addCity.php" method="get" onsubmit="return validateCityInfoForm();">
```

onsumbit I call the javascript function validateCityInfoForm() that looks like this:

```
function validateCityInfoForm() {

                    var xmlhttp;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {// code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                        {


                            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "true") {
                                document.getElementById("checkIfCityExistsWarning").style.display = "block";
                                document.getElementById("checkIfCityExistsWarning").innerHTML = "This city already exists!";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "checkIfCityExists.php?city=" + cityInput + "&country=" + countryInput, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();




}
```

checkIfCityExists.php echoes "true" if the city already exists in the database and "false" otherwise.

The problem is that it always adds the city in the db even though the city already exists.
checkIfCityExists.php returns "true" but it doesn't seem to matter.

I really don't know what the problem is, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

here is checkIfCityExists.php:

```
<?php
include ('database_connection.php');
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['city']);
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['country']);

//check if the city and country already exists in the database
$query_verify = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE name = '$city' AND country = '$country'";
$result_verify = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result_verify) == 0) { //if the city does not appear in the database
    echo "false";
}
else {
    echo "true";
}

?>
```

Comment: I think the issue is in the PHP file. With this code, you just get the result of the request, you don't do anything to the DB.

Comment: Your JS looks fine, adding to the db is done in PHP so the problem would be in that code somewhere.

Comment: post your code where you deal with the DB

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous calls.

Comment: What is returned when you open the `checkIfCityExists.php?city=...` URL in your browser directly?  The issue seems to be in your PHP.

Comment: alert xmlhttp.responseText in IF condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make an asynchronous call to do validation. By the time the call comes back it is too late because the form already is submitted.

Tha Ajax call does not pause the code execution, it makes the call and the rest of the code happens.

What you would need to do it break it up into two steps, make the Ajax call and when the onreadystatechange comes back, submit the form.

Comment: Ajax can hold the execution if Async set to false instead of true

Comment: @YatinTrivedi I know that and it is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your onsubmit has no return.
So `validateCityInfoForm()` returns undefined which does not prevent the Browser from executing the action. `validateCityInfoForm()` should `return false` to prevent the Browser from submitting the form. And then in the `onreadystatechange` call `form.submit()` if necessary.